# How can I compare a NN model and a linear regression?

Tags: neural-network, machine-learning-model, linear-models

I have a small dataset (1500 rows) and to predict the imbalanced target, I am running two linear models (linear regression and lasso) and one nonlinear model (Neural Network) on it. I am using Area Under Precision Recall Curve (AUPRC) to compare the three models. The  baseline in the curve is 10%, AUC for linear regression is 11%, AUC for lasso is 11.2%, and AUC for NN is 11.35%. Can I say that the learning models have improved the random guessing? Is the difference between lasso and NN (11.2% and 11.35%) enough to say the relationships are nonlinear rather than linear? Is there any way (test) to show that the scores are significantly different (such as t-test or p-values)?

Comment: Is this a Classification or Regression problem? I believe you meant LogisticRegression?

Comment: Yes, logistic regression.

Comment: please explain AUPRC ? what purpose does it serve ? Similar values for each of three approaches simply indicates that these approaches are overlapping - based on similar principles.

Comment: "The baseline in the curve is 10%" . Does it mean  a threshold ?

Comment: please explain your data/scores - continuous or Nominal or ratio.